# Trouble importing SVG from tutorial

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I am having trouble importing the SVG file from the tutorial into gazebo recently installed on mac OSX.

When I select the SVG file from the gazebo GUI, the extracted path shows up correctly as in the tutorial, but once I click OK, it does not appear in the environment.

I have tried this with both my own SVG, and the file available on the tutorial page.

Thanks in advance if anyone can give me some pointers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13760/trouble-importing-svg-from-tutorial/) by [powertjp1](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2685/powertjp1/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-06-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2016-06-28**:
Could you run Gazebo in verbose mode and add see if it shows any error messages? If so, please add them to your question. Also mention the Gazebo version you're using.

**Comment by [powertjp1](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2685/powertjp1/) on 2016-06-28**:
I am running version 7.2.0 After running verbose mode, I get the error message:

[Err] [MeshManager.cc:504] GTS library not found. Can not extrude polyline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Unfortunately, it looks like SVG extrusion is not working properly on OSX, see [this](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/1479/gtsmeshutils-delaunay-triangulation-fails) issue.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [powertjp1](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2685/powertjp1/) on 2016-06-29**:
I tried using

*brew install gts*

and building gazebo from source, but I still get the same error

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2016-06-29**:
Ah sorry, I overlooked the fact you're using OSX. I updated the answer.

**Comment by [powertjp1](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2685/powertjp1/) on 2016-06-30**:
Ok, thanks for clarifying